# Azure search indexing csv files

Tags: azure, indexing, azure-cognitive-search

When I try to add an indexer to index csv file from blob storage, it automatically picks some of the fields from the csv file to be added as field name in the index schema but leaves some of the fields. That is probably because the left out fields have spaces or characters that are not allowed as azure search fields. Is there any way I can index all of the fields defined in the csv without changing the file itself?

Comment: Please edit your question and include index definition (especially fields), indexer definition and sample CSV data (including headers).

Comment: the best way would be writing your own indexer. Using the existing one may be limited

Answer (score 0):

Since some column names are invalid index field names, they'll need to be explicitly renamed and the indexer has to be informed of the associations.

1. Create the index with valid field names corresponding to each column you're interested in (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-index)
2. Create the data source to the storage account containing the CSV files (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-data-source)
3. Create an indexer using the above data source and index, and also setting the `fieldMappings`. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-indexer). See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-field-mappings#set-up-field-mappings) for sample JSON to rename fields.